# Why am I getting a return value 3221225477?

Tags: c

I am trying to implement stack in C. I am not getting any compilation error but I am getting the return value as 322122547 without any error. What should I do ?

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack
{
    int size;
    int top;
    int *arr;
};

int isEmpty(struct stack * ptr)
{
    if (ptr->top == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int isFull(struct stack * ptr)
{
    if (ptr->top == ptr->size - 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct stack *s;
    s->size = 10;
    s->top = -1;
    s->arr = (int *)malloc(s->size * sizeof(int));

    if(isEmpty(s)){
        printf("The stack is empty");
    }
    else{
        printf("The stack is not empty");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I use a struct stack pointer I do not get any output. Should I consider changing the pointer part

Comment: In your own words, when you write `struct stack *s;`, what do you expect the value of `s` to be? Are you expecting it to point already at an existing `stack` structure? Why?

Answer (score 3):

Turn on your compiler errors and it will tell you right away what's wrong.  For example if I compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Werror` it says:

```
error: 's' is used uninitialized [-Werror=uninitialized]
    s->size = 10;
  | ~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

Comment: Ok thanks I will try. Any possible solution or should I replace the pointer ?

Comment: Just allocate some memory to hold the struct and store the address in the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem origin**

`struct stack *s;` is defining a pointer that is expecting an instance of your structure. Now by default, that expected structure is not initialized and therefore the pointer points to a random location in memory.

You can visualize this error by using `gcc -Wall -Werror` the compiling and you get:

```
error: 's' is used uninitialized [-Werror=uninitialized]
    s->size = 10;
  | ~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

Since the location the pointer is pointing to is random, you will get random values from your pointer depending on what that memory location contains.

**A solution**

A way to fix this is to initialize the structure your pointer is expecting to point to in order to allocate this structure. You can do this in two way:

- Static allocation: you can create a structure and then point to it using:

```
    struct stack s_static;
    struct stack *s = &s_static;
```

The final code would be:

```
int main()
{
    struct stack s_static;
    struct stack *s = &s_static;
    s->size = 10;
    s->top = -1;
    s->arr = (int *)malloc(s->size * sizeof(int));

    if(isEmpty(s)){
        printf("The stack is empty");
    }
    else{
        printf("The stack is not empty");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- Dynamic allocation: you can dynamically allocate your structure in memory by using `malloc`. You can allocate your stack instance `s` by doing `struct stack* s = (struct stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct stack));`. This is a big line. What's happening? `struct stack* s` tells the compiler this is a pointer that is pointing to a memory location. `(struct stack*)` is telling the malloc that the new memory location we're about to allocate has type `struct stack`. Finally, `malloc` creates some space on the heap for our instance and `sizeof(struct stack)` simply tells the `malloc` command how much memory we need to allocate. After putting this line, the code will compile without errors.

  BUT WAIT! If you use dynamic allocation, you need to also free the heap once you finish, otherwise the memory location will leak. Therefore, before your `return 0`, you need to free that memory location. You can do so by using `free(s)`
  The final dynamic allocation approach will look something like this:

```
int main()
{
    struct stack* s = (struct stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct stack));    
    s->size = 10;
    s->top = -1;
    s->arr = (int *)malloc(s->size * sizeof(int));

    if(isEmpty(s)){
        printf("The stack is empty");
    }
    else{
        printf("The stack is not empty");
    }
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, the return value from `malloc()` should be checked... if `malloc()` returns `NULL` you have a problem.

Comment: Also: don't cast the `malloc` return value and use `malloc(sizeof *s)` and `malloc(s->size * sizeof *s->arr)`.

Comment: In which situations could ```malloc()``` return ```NULL``` for this code just out of interest!